# Prove that the following statements are all logically equivalent.

Tags: elementary-set-theory, logic

> Prove that the following statements are logically equivalent:
>
> 1. $A \subseteq B$
> 2. $A \cap B = A$
> 3. $A \cup B = B$
> 4. $B^c \subseteq A^c$

Here is what I have so far.  I am not sure how much of it is correct or if there is an easier way to go about it.

**Assume $A \subseteq B$ to prove $A \cap B = A$:**

Suppose $x\in A$ since $A \subseteq B$ then $x\in B$.  $\therefore x\in A\cap B$ $\therefore A\subseteq A\cap B$.

**Assume $A \cap B = A$ to prove $A\cup B=B$:**

Suppose $x\in A$ then $x\in A \cap B$ $\therefore$ $x\in B$ from the definition of intersection.  If $x\in B$ then $x\in A\cup B$.  This proves $A\cap B = A \subseteq A\cup B=B$.

**Assume $A\cup B=B$ to prove $B^c \subseteq A^c$:**

???????????????????????????

**Assume $B^c \subseteq A^c$ to prove $A \subseteq B$:**

$x\in A$ implies $x\notin B^c$ because $B^c\subseteq A^c$ hence $x\in B$ and $A\subseteq B$

From this we can see that $x \Leftrightarrow y$ for any $(x,y) \in \{A \subseteq B, A \cap B = A, A\cup B=B, A \subseteq B\}$ because we can get to any statement from any other statement.

Comment: There are 2 kinds of proofs.  (1) When you prove something that is uncertain, using any non-controversial assumption that you want, and (2) When you prove something that is may or may not be certain, but you are restricted to using a specific logical framework.  This is clearly a case of (2), since the statements are obviously equivalent, but you haven't been provided a logical framework to be restricted to.  That makes the question somewhat nonsensical.

Comment: @DanielV Would it be possible to explain what you mean by "logical framework to be restricted to" or provide an example?  As for the question being nonsensical; well you can blame my prof for that.

Comment: If I say "prove 2 + 3 = 5", then it makes sense if I implicitly mean "using peano arithmetic", otherwise there is nothing to prove.  On the other hand, if I say "prove Fermat's Last Theorem", you can generally use any undoubted assumption that you want.  So unless your prof has provided you with very specific definitions for $\subseteq$ and $\cap$ etc to use, there is nothing to prove.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My suggestion for proving is to begin with what you want to prove and in the middle, try to use the assumption. I mean if you want to show $A \subset B$, begin with that $x \in A$ and try to reach $x \in B$.

I write the proof for some cases:

**Assume $B^c \subseteq A^c$ to prove $A \subseteq B$:**

$x \in A \Rightarrow  x \not \in A^c \Rightarrow x \not \in B^c$ (because $ B^c \subseteq A^c) \Rightarrow x \in B$. Therefore $A \subseteq B$.

**Assume $A\cup B=B$ to prove $B^c \subseteq A^c$:**

$x \in B^c \Rightarrow x \not \in B \Rightarrow x \not \in A\cup B \Rightarrow x \not \in A \Rightarrow x \in A^c$. Therefore $B^c \subseteq A^c$.

Answer (score 0):

Your answers are correct.

For the third implication, assume $A \cup B =B$, and let $x \in B^c$. By the definition of complement, $x \in A$ or $x \in A^c$. Suppose towards contradiction that $x \in A$. Then $x \in A \cup B$. But by our assumption this means $x \in B$, a contradiction. Hence $x$ is not in $A$, and so it must be that $x \in A^c$. It follows that $B^c \subseteq A^c$.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that's the correct approach, and your missing argument begins

> If $B = A\cup B$ is assumed, this means that if $x\notin B$, then $\underline{\qquad}$ (by definition of union).